# opencv_traincascade - samplOpenCV Error: Bad argument

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

**Background:** I am trying to train my own OpenCV Haar Classifier for face detection. I am working on a VM with Ubuntu 16.04, my working directory has 2 sub-directories: **face** containing 2429 images of positives, **non-face** containing 4548 images of negatives. All images are png, gray scale and have both width and height 19 pixels. I have generated a file **positives.info** that contains the absolute path to every positive image followed by " 1 0 0 18 18", like so:

```
/home/user/ML-Trainer/face/face1.png 1 0 0 18 18
/home/user/ML-Trainer/face/face2.png 1 0 0 18 18
/home/user/ML-Trainer/face/face3.png 1 0 0 18 18
```

and another file **negatives.txt** that contains the absolute path to every positive image

```
/home/user/ML-Trainer/non-face/other1.png
/home/user/ML-Trainer/non-face/other2.png
/home/user/ML-Trainer/non-face/other3.png
```

First I ran the following command:

```
opencv_createsamples -info positives.info -vec positives.vec -num 2429 -w 19 -h 19
```

and I get the **positives.vec** as expected, I then created a empty directory **data** and ran the following:

```
opencv_traincascade -data data -vec positives.vec -bg negatives.txt -numPos 2429 -numNeg 4548 -numStages 10 -w 19 -h 19 &
```

It seems to run smoothly:

```
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: data
vecFileName: positives.vec
bgFileName: negatives.txt
numPos: 2429
numNeg: 4548
numStages: 10
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 1024
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 1024
acceptanceRatioBreakValue : -1
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 19
sampleHeight: 19
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: BASIC
Number of unique features given windowSize [19,19] : 63960

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   2429 : 2429
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    4548 : 1
Precalculation time: 13
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3| 0.998765| 0.396218|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 0 hours 1 minutes 7 seconds.
```

But then I get the following error:

```
===== TRAINING 1-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS current samplOpenCV Error: Bad argument (Can not get new positive sample. The most possible reason is insufficient count of samples in given vec-file.
) in get, file /home/user/opencv-3.4.0/apps/traincascade/imagestorage.cpp, line 158
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/user/opencv-3.4.0/apps/traincascade/imagestorage.cpp:158: error: (-5) Can not get new positive sample. The most possible reason is insufficient count of samples in given vec-file.
 in function get
```

How do I solve this:

> samplOpenCV Error: Bad argument

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I have modified **-numPos** to a smaller number: **2186** (0.9 * 2429), I did this after reading [this answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/776/error-in-parameter-of-traincascade/) and it got me to

> ===== TRAINING 3-stage =====

and it gives me the same error. How should I tune the parameters for the **opencv_createsamples** command?

Comment: you must reduce the nr of pos samples because you lose some of them in each stage where you don't reach a hit rate of 100%. For minHitRate of 0.999 I typically hold back about 10% of total number, for hR 0.995 you'll probably need more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to make it work by respecting this [formula](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4368/traincascade-error-bad-argument-can-not-get-new-positive-sample-the-most-possible-reason-is-insufficient-count-of-samples-in-given-vec-file/):

> vec-file >= (numPos + (numStages-1) * (1-minHitRate) * (numPose) + S)

numPose - number of positive samples which is used to train each stage

numStages - the count of stages which a cascade classifier will have after the training

S - the count of all the skipped samples from vec-file (for all stages)